# iOS AVSpeechSynthesizer running delegate on 2 ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, delegation, avspeechsynthesizer

I'll start this question trying to explain exactly what I'm trying to do:

I have ViewControllers A and B. Both of them are going to run an AVSpeechSynthesizer reading certain texts. My problem is that I interact the same AVSpeechSynthesizer with UI elements from both VCs, for example:

When I am on VC A I have a row that has a text, I tap on the row and it the AVSpeechSynthesizer produces the Speech. My Delegate method runs and the Progress bar is updated every second. But when I tap another time on the same row, I have to Push another new VC into the NavigationController and in this new VC I have the same elements (Progress bar, play/pause button) and this UI I can't get it updated with the Delegate that runs on the previous VC. The Audio doesn't stop, but the controls from VC B does not get updated by the AVSpeechSynthesizer delegate from VC A.

In short:
2 ViewControllers, same UI components (Play/Pause button, Progress Bar), Only one AVSpeechSynthesizer with delegation fetching 2 UIs at the same time.

This is my first question in years around here and I am afraid I am not being very clear with my problem. I can try to explain more if it's not.

Comment: Is the problem that the Play/Pause button does not show as the pause button in `ViewController` B?

Comment: Hi @Caleb ! Yes, and the progress bar from ViewController B should also receive data from the Delegate inside ViewController A